# Parrallel ongoing for each file loop?

Tags: background-process

I want to continuously monitor some log files. What I have below works if I switch the `tail -F` for `cat $log_file`. When I use `-tail -F` the first log file works but because its process doesn't finish it blocks the top `while` loop.

How can I background each process so that the outer `while read log_file` starts a process for each log file? *(also tried adding `&` in various places to background the inner while loop)*

```
ls /var/log/myApp-*.log | while read log_file ; do
  tail -F $log_file while read log ; do
    echo send $log to external tracker for $log_file if X
  done
done
```

Comment: the above code looks pretty redundant. What's the approximate content of `log_file`?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest removed the inside of the loop because it seemed irrelevant to what I'm asking. But my situation is this. I have a bunch of log files where each line *(should)* be a single json object. In the format of `{ "name": "PeriodicWork", "hostname": "myHost", "pid": 12189.20, "level": 20, "msg": "Executing [CheckFailedTask NodeId=8]", "time": "2017-12-04T00:20:30.953Z", "v": 0 }` I need to check if the level is 50 or over and if so send `msg`, `pid`, and `name` to another server.

Comment: @don_crissti, I'm afraid that the current question implies more than 2 tailed files

Comment: @don_crissti if I just tail multiple files like that I won't be able to tell what output is associated with what file, won't it just all look like a single input? I think I specifically need the structure of the double while loop here which isn't the case for the Q/A linked.

Comment: can you elaborate where is *parent log_file* in your code?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest not sure what you mean? `$log_file` is each result from `ls /var/log/myApp-*.log`.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest are you asking about what the `echo` code would be in the real version?

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses `awk` to parse the output of tail and call a command with `system()` if the event is detected.

Also, you might want to avoid parsing the output of `ls` and using globbing instead.

```
for log_file in /var/log/myApp-*.log; do 
    tail -F $log_file | awk '{l=gensub(/.+\"level\": ([0-9]+).+/,"\\1","g",$0); if(l>50 && l!= $0){system("echo command")}}' &
done
```